# opj_encode for OpenJPEG is seg faulting

Tags: c++, parameters, encoder, jpeg2000

I am a newbie to OpenJPEG and am trying to use the its libraries to create a c++ app that takes in image files and encodes them into J2k format. I create default parameters, `opj_set_default_encoder_parameters(&params)` and set the outfile value. Using those parameters, I create the image `image = bmptoimage(filename, &params)` and set the x and y of the parameters to the image size. `opj_setup_encoder(encoder, &params, image)` returns successful, but the following code:

```
opj_start_compress(encoder, image, stream);
opj_encode(encoder, stream);  //seg fault here
opj_end_compress(encoder, stream);
```

I get a signal 11 seg fault in the opj_encode function.

I think I am not setting an important parameter, but I cannot find anything to indicate which parameter it could be. Which parameter could it be?

It might also be that I am creating the stream object incorrectly, `stream = opj_stream_create_default_file_stream(params.outfile, OPJ_FALSE);`

Thanks

UPDATE

I have figured out that `opj_encode` is seg faulting because opj_start_compress is failing. It fails with the error "Number of resolutions is too high in comparsion to the size of tiles". I have entered `params.numresolution = 1;` (0 causes a malloc error), but I still get the same error. Any idea why `opj_start_compress` would fail?

Answer (score 1):

I just call this answered. `opj_encode` is failing because `opj_start_compress` is not succeeding. Putting in a check to verify the success of `opj_start_compress` before encoding fixed the seg fault.